# Rollup Javascript API: rollup.watch process never dies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, rollup

I use Rollup to bundle my express server applicaton. I try to use rollup Javascript API. I've got 2 separated scripts to manage rollup actions: one for building project on demand, and another for continously watching src directory. Each one, if needed, is started from command line as node process, like so: "node [file.name.js]".

Package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "watch:exp": "env NODE_ENV=DEVELOPMENT node project_configuration/rollup.watch.js",
    "build:exp": "env NODE_ENV=PRODUCTION node project_configuration/rollup.build.js",
  },
```

Content of both files is actually the same as proposed content in rollup documentation. For watch mode script, that would be:

```
    let counter = 0;
    const watcher = rollup.watch(watchOptions); // param contains entry, output dir, externals and plugins, according to docs.

    watcher.on('event', event => {
        const evs = ['END', 'ERROR'];

        if (evs.includes(event.code)) {
            counter += 1;
            console.log(`Rollup watcher now bundled ${counter} times`);
        }
    });

    watcher.close();
```

When i use command "npm run watch:exp", project starts, but when I use "ctrl+c" on bash command line, process is not aborted - saving src directory causes re-building project and loging string with incremented counter to the console. Moreover, i would like to not only rebuild, but to run my project as well, on every save, so i use plugin:

`@rollup/plugin-run`

to START MY SERVER ON PORT 5000 after every rebuilding. And it fails with error:

`Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000`

To be clear: just in-case, I patiently rebooted machine several times (in order to kill any "weird", uncontrolled node processes) and changed port after that. I tried several ports between 5001 and 8080, and it doesn't succed. It always ended up with EADDRINUSE with current port number.

So I tried to put everything in async function, like so:

```
let counter = 0;
async function watchMe () {
    const watcher = await rollup.watch(watchOptions);

    watcher.on( ...counter stuff here )

    watcher.close();
}

watchMe();
```

Now, i still can't abort process (ctrl+c on bash CLI), but It fixed "eddrinuse" error at least. So when I run "npm run watch:exp", process starts, bundle is created, counter incremented, and server runs on port 5000. After saving src dir, rebuild is triggered, counter incremented, and server again work correctly on port 5000. But:

1. I have no idea WHY it works.
2. Still, i cannot abort watcher (and because of this, i cannot abort process triggered by watcher plugin @rollup/plugin-run), when aborting "npm run watch:exp" process with ctrl+c.

I have found literally nothing in rollup docs: only these lines of example code that I copied into my project, and then changed into async function. It seems that there is neither doc, nor tutorial, about how to use rollup.watch API, or where (and how) to use "close()" method correctly. I would appreciate any advice as much as examples of source code (links to repo), in order to just check, how rollup js API is used in existing project. Right now, I don't see such examples anywhere. On the other hand, I don't see any issuses or threats similar to my problem on statck, github or npm.

P.S. To be clear: my config works with rollup.config.js file and "rollup --config rollup.config.js" way. But this is not the case. I want to know, how to use it throught js API

--- edit ---

I forgot to mention:

1. system windows 10 x64;
2. node version latest;
3. when watcher.close() is called in body of callback function given to watcher events, watcher exits correctly after first build, but child process of run() plugin still runs and server occupies port 5000

```
watcher.on('event', () => { 
   if (event === 'END') watcher.close() 
})
```